# jQuery - why each can't get the width of hidden elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, each, outerwidth

Why each can't get the width of hidden elements?

My code:

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navbar-items">
  <li><a>one</a></li>
  <li><a>two</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="navbar-items hidden">
  <li><a>one</a></li>
  <li><a>two</a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".navbar-items > li > a").each(function(index) {
    console.log(this);
    var thisWidth = $(this).outerWidth(true);
    console.log(thisWidth);
  });
</script>
```

Result:

```
<a>​one​</a>​
25
<a>​two​</a>​
26
<a>​one​</a>​
2
<a>​two​</a>​
2
```

But I thought it should be:

```
<a>​one​</a>​
25
<a>​two​</a>​
26
<a>​one​</a>​
25
<a>​two​</a>​
26
```

Any ideas? How can I get the width of these hidden elements?

**EDIT:**

I can get the width of the hidden element here:

```
<a class="show">Hello World</a>
<a class="hidden">Hello World</a>

console.log($('.show').outerWidth(true));
console.log($('.hidden').outerWidth(true));
```

Result:

```
81
81
```

Why?

Comment: two
<a>one</a>
23
<a>two</a>
24
<a>one</a>
23
<a>two</a>
24. This is the output I am getting.

Comment: So I think it is working as it is expected. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @AbdulAleemKhan check it again with `.hidden {
  display: none;
}`

Comment: Hidden elements have no dimensions since they take up no space

Comment: with '.hidden {display: none;}' it is not assigned any space on page so it is zero. Do you want an alternative so that you can get the width and height of that field. Well you can add attributes to the html and then you can get the attributes values. @teelou

Comment: for example data attribute to input tag and then you can give values of width and height. But if you want to calculate the auto width and height. Then easy way to do it will be getting the width and height of the visible similar elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something really hacky by cloning and turning visibility off. Once it's been inserted it into the DOM, we remove it after the width has been taken.

```js
var appHook = $('body');

$(".navbar-items > li > a").each(function(index) {
  var element = $(this).clone();
  element.css({ visibility: 'hidden' });
  appHook.append(element);
  console.log(element.outerWidth());
  element.remove();
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="navbar-items">
  <li><a>one</a></li>
  <li><a>two</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="navbar-items hidden">
  <li><a>one</a></li>
  <li><a>two</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for the hack!